# How to pass string parameter in wcf restful service from URL

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I am new to wcf services. I have developed a simple restful service. I need to insert string data to the database table which is passed from URL. 
Please refer the below code.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddBook/{name}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ServiceResponse AddBook(string name);
```

Implemented AddBook method in svc file to insert the data into table.

```
public ServiceResponse AddBook(string name)
{
    ServiceResponse sobj = new ServiceResponse();
    try
    {
        if (name != null)
        {
            using(SampleContext sc = new SampleContext())
            {
                book book = new book();
                book.BookName = name.ToString();
                sc.books.Add(book);
                sc.SaveChanges();
                sobj.packet.header.responseCode = BookUtility.GNRL_SUCCESS_CODE;
                sobj.packet.header.responseStatus = BookUtility.SUCCESS_STATUS;
                sobj.packet.header.responseMessage = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sobj.packet.header.responseCode = BookUtility.GNRL_INVALID_INPUT_CODE;
            sobj.packet.header.responseStatus = BookUtility.ERROR_STATUS;
            sobj.packet.header.responseMessage = UtilityResource.ResourceManager.GetString(BookUtility.GNRL_INVALID_INPUT_CODE);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
    }
    return sobj;
}
```

when I try to pass string data through URL as below I am getting error as no end point found.

> http://localhost/WCF_Entity_Books/BookService.svc/AddBook?name=Family

Please find below my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="MytestWCF_Entity.BookService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="MytestWCF_Entity.IBookService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/bookservice"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings><add name="SampleContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SampleModel.csdl|res://*/SampleModel.ssdl|res://*/SampleModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Sample;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check your method . I think you have used GET in request. It should be POST

Comment: Can you show your Web.config

Comment: @NoxiousReptile please check web.config in my post.

Comment: Can you tell how you checked it. I recreated your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @NoxiousReptile, through browser its not workig, but its working if I use Postman

Comment: There two issues I see here: 1. Service base address and address in url is not matcing. 2. When you copy past url in browser and hit enter its "GET" request whereas your method supports only POST method.

Comment: @anitha lm The browser always sends GET request only. Inrder to make it POST you should use Postman or Restclient. dont worry your code is working fine. If you change your method from POST  to GET it will work in browser also.

Comment: @NoxiousReptile,you are correct. I was using browser to perform post request

Comment: @anitha lm Good luck....